# How to validate a facebook username with a single regular expression?

Tags: node.js, regex, facebook, validation

The rules for a facebook username state the following

> Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a period (“.”), and must be at least 5 characters long.
>
> They can not contain .com, or .net.

ref: https://www.facebook.com/help/105399436216001

What regular expresssion could I use to validate a username against these rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^(?!.*\.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$
```

```js
console.log(/^(?!.*\.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$/.test('abc')); // too short
console.log(/^(?!.*\.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$/.test('tim.com')); // contains .com
console.log(/^(?!.*\.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$/.test('abc$#')); // forbidden characters

console.log(/^(?!.*\.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$/.test('ABC123')); // matches
```

Note: If you want to also match lowercase letters, then use `[A-Za-z0-9.]`, or make the regex literal case insensitive with the `i` flag.